# Full calendar custom agendaWeek view with custom Week titles

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have created fullcalendar custom agendaWeek view for 14 days. It works fine and I need to customize it as following.
[image]

Week title should display Even and Odd title as above.

My custom view code as follows.

```
agendaTwoweeks: {
        type: 'agendaWeek',
        columnFormat: 'ddd',
        duration: { days: 14 }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible using the standard options. Perhaps you could request it as a feature.

Comment: Or you could fork the agenda view and make a totally custom view which implements your extra requirement - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js